# SQL - Counting the number of rows that contain two distinct fields

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way of getting a count of fieldB but only where fieldA and fieldB combination is unique?

For example

```
fieldA     fieldB
X          A
X          B
Y          C
X          B
Y          A
```

A count of field B would return:

```
A = 2
B = 1
C = 1
```

I've tried using 'SELECT DISTINCT fieldA, COUNT(fieldB) AS count FROM table GROUP BY fieldB'. This seems to return a count of all the values in fieldB, not just the ones that have a unique fieldA.

I hope what i'm trying to do makes sense, I'm finding it difficult to put into words. Is what i'm trying to do possible with SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
SELECT fieldB, COUNT(DISTINCT  fieldA, fieldB) AS count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY fieldB;
```

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers, this is just the first one I tried it and seems to work perfectly. - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   fieldA, COUNT(fieldB) AS count from
(SELECT DISTINCT fieldA, fieldB FROM table)a
FROM a GROUP BY a.fieldB
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you there

```
Declare @mytbl table (fieldA char(1), fieldB char(1))
insert into @mytbl
select 'X','A'
union all select 'X','B'
union all select 'Y','C'
union all select 'X','B'
union all select 'Y','A'

select COUNT(*), LEFT(myfields,1)
from 
(
select distinct fieldb + fielda as myfields
from @mytbl
group by fieldb + fielda
) a
group by LEFT(myfields,1)
```

Returns

2   A
1   B
1   C

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mytb table
(
fieldA varchar(10),
fieldB varchar(10)
);

INSERT into @mytb values('X','A');
INSERT into @mytb values('X','B');
INSERT into @mytb values('Y','C');
INSERT into @mytb values('X','B');
INSERT into @mytb values('Y','A');

SELECT fieldB,count(DISTINCT fieldA+fieldB) as count
from @mytb
group BY fieldB;


   fieldB     count
---------- -----------
    A          2
    B          1
    C          1
```

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Sorry But It returns 2 for A.